# remove certain value in nested list

Tags: python

so I have a list

```py
[['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], ['2', '3', '4', '5', ''], ['1', '3', '2', '4', '5'], ['2', '4', '3', '1', '5'], ['2', '1', '3', '4', '5'], ['1', '3', '2', '4', '5'], ['5', '', '', '', ''], ['5', '1', '2', '4', '3'], ['4', '1', '2', '5', '3'], ['1', '2', '3', '4', ''], ['2', '3', '4', '5', '1'], ['1', '4', '2', '', ''], ['3', '4', '2', '', ''], ['4', '3', '', '', '']]
```

and I wanna remove all the '' from the list so I can iterate over it without an error, i've tried using for loops but keep getting error s

Comment: Can you show us the code that you're running and the errors that are coming up for you?

Comment: In some sense, you are going to have to iterate over the list to remove the values, so there's little difference between removing them and simply ignoring them. (If anything, removing them is *harder*, because you'll be changing the structure of the nested list in the process.)

Answer (score 2):

```
l = [['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], ['2', '3', '4', '5', ''], ['1', '3', '2', '4', '5'], ['2', '4', '3', '1', '5'], ['2', '1', '3', '4', '5'], ['1', '3', '2', '4', '5'], ['5', '', '', '', ''], ['5', '1', '2', '4', '3'], ['4', '1', '2', '5', '3'], ['1', '2', '3', '4', ''], ['2', '3', '4', '5', '1'], ['1', '4', '2', '', ''], ['3', '4', '2', '', ''], ['4', '3', '', '', '']]
[[e for e in sublist if e != ''] for sublist in l]
```